# Processing an HTML form with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

**Well, I have gotten the submit to work... somehow.  But the email comes and it only contains my email as the body of the message (not even the email entered into the form)... no name, no phone number, no radio answers, ect.**

Ok.  I have finally gotten the html form to do SOMETHING.  Unfortunately, when you hit "submit" it directs to a page that says this: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$name          = $_POST['name'];
$telephone     = $_POST['phone'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];

//Validate first
if (empty($name) || empty($visitor_email)) {
    echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
    exit;
}

if (IsInjected($visitor_email)) {
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}

$email_from    = 'heather@thetrinitydesign.com'; //<== update the email address
$email_subject = "New Form submission";
$email_body    = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n" . "Here is the message:\n $message" . $to = "heather@thetrinitydesign.com"; //<== update the email address
$headers       = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank_you.html');


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
    $injections = array(
        '(\n+)',
        '(\r+)',
        '(\t+)',
        '(%0A+)',
        '(%0D+)',
        '(%08+)',
        '(%09+)'
    );
    $inject     = join('|', $injections);
    $inject     = "/$inject/i";
    if (preg_match($inject, $str)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

?>
```

And the HTML.  I feel like I need to have each of the questions I asked represented in the PHP file. Is this correct? And I have seen so many things preface the $POST thing that I am completely lost.

```
<form action="form-to-email.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  name="Info Form" id="Info Form">
    <p class="form">Name:
      <input name="Name" type="text" class="formbox" id="Name" size="20" />
    </p>
    <p class="form"> Phone:
   <input name="Phone" type="text" class="formbox" id="Phone" size="12" maxlength="12"     /></p>
    <p class="form">Email:
      <span id="sprytextfield2">
      <input name="Email" type="text" class="formbox" id="Email" />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span  class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span> </p>
    <p class="form">
      <label>Have you ever had Custom Interior Design work before?<br />
```

Here is the submit:

```
<br />
<input name="Submit" type="submit" id="button"  value="Submit" />
<br />
</p>
<p class="form">
```

Comment: Submit button: <br />
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="button"  value="Submit" />
    <br />
    </p>
    <p class="form">

Comment: You have a rogue `$` in your code. It's pretty obvious.

Comment: "More information about this error may be available in the server error log." — So look in the error log!

Comment: You never indented any code in your life yet?

Comment: I would advice to use that IsInjected function on all values you receive from the form. Never trust any user input ;) Better yet, why not just use htmlspecialchars? It might also be nice to mention you didn't write this code and got it from http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/php-form-to-email.html

Comment: Oh yes, none of the php is mine. which is why I have been experimenting with what I can find online.  Can anyone direct me to some code that I can use with the HTLM form I created or seriously walk me step by step saying, do this first.  DO this second, this code third...

Comment: Indented code?  Yes, I indented it.  But it didn't work like it said it would on here.

Answer (score 0):

Just above the validate first comment is a $ that should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are flying by the seat of your pants, and are just trying to get it working.  Spend a little more time learn what is actually happening.

[PHP Forms](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) a great tutorial on how to get forms working.

a few things to note:

1. santize your $_POST data. make sure all data is safe. not just your email data.
2. look into coding standards, there a bunch, pick one [drupals coding standards](https://drupal.org/coding-standards)
3. give all form elements a name and id, not just an id,  when you get into javscript later on, which you may or may not, this will be much easier.
4. avoid spaces in ids/names  form name='Info Form'  not a huge deal, could get ugly later on.
5. you can run the php file from command line, and get some good error details there.
6. turn on php error reporting [Show Errors](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/let-php-show-all-errors)

these are just a few, not trying to be smug, trying to point you in the right direction.

EDIT:

change this:

```
 $email_from    = 'heather@thetrinitydesign.com'; //<== update the email address
 $email_subject = "New Form submission";
 $email_body    = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n" . "Here is the message:\n $message" . $to = "heather@thetrinitydesign.com"; //<== update the email address
 $headers       = "From: $email_from \r\n";
 $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
 //Send the email!
 mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
```

to this:

```
 $message = "Hello My Friend";
 $email_from    = 'heather@thetrinitydesign.com';
 $email_subject = "New Form submission";
 $email_body    = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n" . "Here is the message:\n $message";
 $to = $_POST['Email']; //<== update the email address
 $headers       = "From: $email_from \r\n";
 $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
 //Send the email!
 mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
```

This will send an email from heather@thetrinitydesign.com to "what ever you type in email"

with the message
 "You have received a new message from the user "what ever you type in name"

"Here is the message:

Hello My Friend";

Comment: Yes, flying by seat of pants.  Absolutely. NO idea where to start. NO idea how to read/speak/write php.  And no other way to to make a HTML form send to an email...

Comment: For example, when I say no idea, "To display the submitted data you could simply echo all the variables".  This is from the link you mentioned.  No idea what it means.  And it's about the second sentence!

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have read through this and it is of no help for me  I already have the form created and a submit button.  I didn't see any mention of submit buttons in the link. I read through it a couple times last night and today.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
<input name="Submit" type="submit" id="button"  value="Submit" />
```

to

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="button"  value="Submit" />
             ^ This should be lowercase here, see below
```

The code below needs to match the name above.... exactly...

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                   ^ here!!!!
```

---

These two values need to match exactly...

```
$_POST['THIS'] and <input name="THIS" .../>
```

---

As Quinny has pointed out, you make this error with almost all the form inputs...

```
<input name="Email" .../> should be <input name="email" .../>
<input name="Phone" .../> should be <input name="phone" .../>
<input name="Name" ..../> should be <input name="name" ..../>
```

Comment: This also applies to the other inputs, they need to be lowercased to match up when setting the three variables with the posted data.

Answer (score 0):

As well as all of the suggestions mentioned, I am going to hazard a guess that the internal error is because the form is posting to 'form-to-email.php', this needs to match the filename of your php file.